# type error this reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть 2 куска кода

```
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
  return this.reduce((a,b) => a +b, 0);
}
```

И

```
Array.prototype.sum1 = () =>this.reduce((a,b) => a +b, 0);
```

Почему при вызове

```
console.log([1,2,3].sum())
```

Отобразится верный результат, а если вызвать

```
console.log([1,2,3].sum1())
```

Бросит TypeError?

Comment: `sim1` - это, случаем, не опечатка?

Comment: Да. там опечатка, потому что руками переписал неправильно код, но вопрос остается актуальным даже при вызове sum1().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что

> Стрелочные функции не создают собственный контекст `this`, а используют значение `this` окружающего контекста.